# Retrolambda: Lint crashes when using lambda expressions with retrolambda

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint, android-lint, retrolambda

I'm trying to use [retrolambda](https://github.com/orfjackal/retrolambda) along with [gradle-retrolambda](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda) plugin. In general it works fine, but when I compile for release, the `lint` stage fails with exception:

```
:playground.dagger:lintVitalReleaseFailed converting ECJ parse tree to Lombok for file D:\....\playground\dagger\MainActivity.java
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown ASTNode child: LambdaExpression
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitOther(EcjTreeVisitor.java:368)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitEcjNode(EcjTreeVisitor.java:364)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.visit(EcjTreeConverter.java:295)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.toTree(EcjTreeConverter.java:236)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:282)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:252)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.access$100(EcjTreeConverter.java:141)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter$2.visitMessageSend(EcjTreeConverter.java:1042)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitEcjNode(EcjTreeVisitor.java:156)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.visit(EcjTreeConverter.java:295)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.toTree(EcjTreeConverter.java:236)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:282)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:252)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.toBlock(EcjTreeConverter.java:397)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.access$1500(EcjTreeConverter.java:141)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter$2.visitMethodDeclaration(EcjTreeConverter.java:1241)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitEcjNode(EcjTreeVisitor.java:152)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.visit(EcjTreeConverter.java:295)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.toTree(EcjTreeConverter.java:236)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:282)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:252)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.access$100(EcjTreeConverter.java:141)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter$2.createNormalTypeBody(EcjTreeConverter.java:563)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter$2.visitTypeDeclaration(EcjTreeConverter.java:486)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitEcjNode(EcjTreeVisitor.java:48)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.visit(EcjTreeConverter.java:295)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.toTree(EcjTreeConverter.java:236)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:282)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.fillList(EcjTreeConverter.java:252)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.access$100(EcjTreeConverter.java:141)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter$2.visitCompilationUnitDeclaration(EcjTreeConverter.java:441)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeVisitor.visitEcjNode(EcjTreeVisitor.java:264)
    at lombok.ast.ecj.EcjTreeConverter.visit(EcjTreeConverter.java:295)
    at com.android.tools.lint.EcjParser.parseJava(EcjParser.java:407)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.JavaVisitor.visitFile(JavaVisitor.java:236)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkJava(LintDriver.java:1491)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.runFileDetectors(LintDriver.java:1026)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.checkProject(LintDriver.java:882)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:433)
    at com.android.tools.lint.client.api.LintDriver.analyze(LintDriver.java:374)
    at com.android.tools.lint.LintCliClient.run(LintCliClient.java:130)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient.run(LintGradleClient.java:112)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LintGradleClient$run.call(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.runLint(Lint.groovy:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.this$4$runLint(Lint.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$this$4$runLint$1.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lintSingleVariant(Lint.groovy:173)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint$lintSingleVariant$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.Lint.lint(Lint.groovy:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildModelAction.run(BuildModelAction.java:30)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ConfiguringBuildAction.run(ConfiguringBuildAction.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:70)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:119)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there anything to do about it? Of course, a trivial work/around would be to disable `lint` check for release. But I'm looking for solution, allowing to keep `lint`.

Following is app's module `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

configurations {
    apt
}

android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven{
        url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/'
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:1.8.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0-SNAPSHOT'
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
}
```

Root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:2.5.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem since some time and unfortunately could not find a solution yet.. It might be caused because `lint` uses a `lombok-ast` fork that is not able to deal with lambdas. See: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/tools/+/master/common/lombok-ast/PREBUILT

Comment: You said 'since some time': do you mean that you were able to use lambdas in the past, without having lint complaining about it?

Comment: Not sure, I only remember that I was already using lambdas for maybe a month or two before I first noticed the problem. But I was mostly using Android Studio to build. The problem then became visible after a gradle build from command line.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I found out I can compile a signed apk under debug, but not under release.

Comment: @EduardoBonet, sure because by default lint check is enabled for release configuration. You will be able to build for release if you disable the lint check. Just add the following line: `lintOptions { checkReleaseBuilds false }` within the `android` section

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use a [special lombok version](https://github.com/evant/android-retrolambda-lombok) with lint which does not whine about Java 8 features.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        ...
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:<version>'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:<version>'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2'
    }

    // Exclude the version that the android plugin depends on.
    configurations.classpath.exclude group: 'com.android.tools.external.lombok'
}
```

This way you can keep running lint on the whole project, even with the latest versions of the Android Gradle plugin.

*Note:* If you receive same errors, try to put the configuration above into the top most `build.gradle` file. It should work then.

Answer (score 19):

There is a GitHub issue that discusses this problem: https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda/issues/96

One of the comments in the issue mentions that `lint` never actually worked with retrolambda but rather, with the newest `lint` version, is now "failing loudly" instead of simply skipping the rest of the file when a lambda was encountered.

With this in mind, it seems like there are two options. One, you could simply disable `lint` like you mentioned in your question. Of course the problem with this is that you would lose the benefit of `lint` scanning the rest of your code. The second option is to roll back your `lint` version such that it is no longer "failing loudly" but rather simply skips checking the lambda-related source; this way, `lint` can still scan the rest of your application source code.

According to the GitHub issue, rolling back your `lint` version from `24.0.1` (you might have a different version) to `24.0.0` seems to fix the problem. You can find this information in the issue (link posted at beginning of answer).